# How to capture a changing one line program output?

Tags: io-redirection, windows-subsystem-for-linux

A program outputs various data lines to the same line in a timely order, overwriting the line in each line write. How can I capture all of its output lines and write them to a file separated by newlines? 
Regular redirection would not do it.

Comment: *Regular redirection would not do it.* Have you tried? The data will be in the file anyway.

Comment: Yes I have tried. The program removes all of its output in the end and so even if something could have been written it would still get overwritten with blank.

Comment: *The program removes all of its output in the end* How do you know?  Did you simply redirect output to a file, then `cat` that file?

Comment: No. I watched it in my terminal. It displays a few lines replaced going on for a few seconds and then it erases back to the start and a bash prompt reappears in the beginning of the line like the program never ran.

Comment: *No. I watched it in my terminal.* So, you've never actually tried redirection?  That means you don't really know whether or not redirection actually works.

Comment: I did try redirection, like this: &> file

Comment: So how did you check the contents of the file?

Comment: with the 'cat' command.... I guess it might be a good idea now to move to chat until we find a solution.

Comment: If there is any data in the file, using `cat` will likely replicate any screen/cursor manipulation the process does.  Assuming Linux/Unix, something like `od -c file` or `od -x file` to see the actual characters or hex codes for any
 bytes in the file.

Comment: It shows 00000000 . The file is also 0 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is done using `\r`, which returns the cursor to the beginning of the current line without moving to the next line, and that the program in question is sending its output to its standard output, converting all the `\r` characters in the program’s output to `\n` will produce the result you’re after:

```
yourprogram | tr '\r' '\n' > logfile
```

See the difference between

```
printf "Hello\rworld\n"
```

and

```
printf "Hello\rworld\n" | tr '\r' '\n'
```

Note that without this, redirecting to a log file *will* store all the output in the file; you’d be able to see it by viewing the file using `less` rather than `cat`. (`less` will show `\r` as `^M`, without overwriting the previous line.)

If the program is writing directly to the terminal, this won’t help. In that case, you’ll need to use a program capable of capturing all the terminal output too; one example is `script`:

```
script -c yourprogram logfile
```

will start the program and capture all its output to `logfile`. You’ll need to process the special characters in the logfile to make sense of it — `less` will help you there (or any reasonable editor).

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Running the first command without redirection it eliminates the output to stdout at all. And with redirection the file gets empty.

Comment: It occurred to me that this might be an issue — see my update.

Comment: Wait — do you want to see the output while it’s being logged?

Comment: i don't mind. I use WSL so I cannot use script. See: https://superuser.com/questions/1249475/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-logging-bash-sessions